# dot products on sparse matrices

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, dot-product

I'm trying to take the dot product of a row in a sparse matrix with the transpose of that row using Python. I have a huge sparse matrix called X2. And I am saving the results (which is supposed to be a single number) in a list called Njc.

```
    X2 = X.transpose()
    for row in X2:
        Njc.append(dot(row,row.transpose()))
```

However, when I run my program, the results are not single numbers. They look like:
  (0, 0)    355

(0, 0)    295

(0, 0)    15

(0, 0)    204

(0, 0)    66

....

Unfortunately my sparse matrix is so huge that I can't make it into a dense matrix (my memory will blow up). Is there a way to get only the numbers on the right without the couples on the left?

Comment: out of curiosity, how big is the matrix?

Comment: it is 1 million by 10 thousand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dot` is returning a sparse matrix. To pick out the one value inside the sparse matrix, you could use `.todense().item()`:

```
Njc.append((np.dot(row, row.transpose())).todense().item())
```

Comment: why can't I do this? I am doing dot operations with sparse matrix too, but when I do 'todense' it gives me error that ndarray object has no attribute 'todense'

Comment: @dsutandi: A SciPy [sparse matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) is not a NumPy `ndarray`. Your matrix might be sparse in the mathematical sense, but it does not appear to be a SciPy sparse matrix.